# Anything I can do? High CPU load on server and not able to login

Tags: high-load

I just purchased a dedi server (Atom dual core)
After I resynced and transferred the whole website, I have one of the scripts that required GD module to be installed , I didn't know that so it made a very huge load on the server.

Right now, I cannot log to the server due to the very high CPU usage. I cannot use SSH nor anything.

The company has very slow supporting system and I'm waiting for their reply for 2 days now.

Is there anything I can do by my self at this point?  The company most probably will ask me for a 50$ fee for this.

Comment: wven with very high load (loadavg > 15) it has never happened to me that I was not able to login with ssh

Comment: I use CyberDucks to login with terminal but it does not allow me to log in at all.  Shall I use putty?

Comment: My suggestion is to change hosting companies.  2 days for a response is unacceptable.  A $50 fee is OK depending on what you're asking them to do: If they're going to log in on the console and find/fix the problem that's a great rate. If all they're going to do is power-cycle the machine (and you don't ask them to do this all the time) it's insane.  Just my $0.02

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do other than:

1. Use ssh but just wait for the login. Depending how heavily the server is loaded, and the type of load, ssh may be able to login eventually. You may have to increase the client's timeout value (exactly how depends on the client).
2. Use the remote reboot/power control to reboot the server assuming you have one. I wouldn't get a dedicated server without one as it makes fixing these kinds of issues trivial.
3. Use the remote KVM access (again, assuming you have one).